# Undo\Redo with multi items movement QGraphicScene - pyqt5

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have implemented **QUndoStack** with **QGraphicScene** and everything is working like charm with individual **QGraphicItem** movement/rotation, but when it comes to the multi-items movement, I couldn't find any way to do so, since I didn't find any flag/signal that will be emitted after all selected item position has been changed **[ NOT DURING]**.

Here is a sketch code that will represent my goals.

```
import sys
from typing import Dict

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsItem, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, \
    QGraphicsEllipseItem, QUndoStack, QUndoCommand
import random


class CustomUndoRedoStack(QUndoStack):
    instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not CustomUndoRedoStack.instance:
            CustomUndoRedoStack.instance = self
            super(CustomUndoRedoStack, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        return CustomUndoRedoStack.instance


class MovingMultiItemsCommand(QUndoCommand):

    def __init__(self, new_items_pos: Dict[QGraphicsItem], old_items_pos: Dict[QGraphicsItem]):
        super(MovingMultiItemsCommand, self).__init__()
        self.new_items_pos = new_items_pos
        self.old_items_pos = old_items_pos
        CustomUndoRedoStack.get_instance().push(self)

    def undo(self) -> None:
        for item in self.old_items_pos:
            item.setPos(self.old_items_pos[item])
        super(MovingMultiItemsCommand, self).undo()

    def redo(self) -> None:
        for item in self.new_items_pos:
            item.setPos(self.new_items_pos[item])
        super(MovingMultiItemsCommand, self).redo()


class CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem, self).__init__(x, y, 20, 20)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 128, 0), 0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 128, 20, 128)))


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self._isPanning = False
        self._mousePressed = False
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


class MyGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsScene, self).__init__()
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(50, 50, 50)))
        self.old_items_pos = {}
        self.new_items_pos = {}

    #  ------- I want something like the following -----------------------------

    def selected_items_before_change(self):
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            self.old_items_pos[item] = item.pos()

    def selected_items_after_change(self):
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            self.new_items_pos[item] = item.pos()

    def selected_item_position_changed(self):
        """
        This method must be triggered only and only once after selected items position has been changed (NOT WHILE)
        """
        MovingMultiItemsCommand(self.new_items_pos, self.old_items_pos)

    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.gv = MyGraphicsView()
        self.gv.setScene(MyGraphicsScene())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gv)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        scene = self.gv.scene()

        for i in range(500):
            x = random.randint(0, 1000)
            y = random.randint(0, 1000)
            rect = CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y)
            scene.addItem(rect)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyMainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**C++ answers will be good as well, but Python is preferable :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse movement of selectable items is handled by the graphics scene, starting with its `mousePressEvent()` and ending with the corresponding `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

This means that you can create a QUndoCommand based on the selected items (if any) after the default implementation of mouse button press/release is called. This will be valid for any movement, including when just one item has been moved.

```py
class ItemMovedUndoCommand(QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, oldPositions, newPositions):
        if len(oldPositions) == 1:
            pos = oldPositions.values()[0]
            text = 'Item moved to {}x{}'.format(
                pos.x(), pos.y())
        else:
            text = '{} items moved'.format(len(oldPositions))
        super().__init__(text)
        self.oldPositions = oldPositions
        self.newPositions = newPositions

    def redo(self):
        for item, pos in self.newPositions.items():
            item.setPos(pos)

    def undo(self):
        for item, pos in self.oldPositions.items():
            item.setPos(pos)


class CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem, self).__init__(-10, -10, 20, 20)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 128, 0), 
            0.5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 128, 20, 128)))


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self._isPanning = False
        self._mousePressed = False
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)


class MyGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    itemsMoved = pyqtSignal(object, object)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGraphicsScene, self).__init__()
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(50, 50, 50)))
        self.oldPositions = {}

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.oldPositions = {i:i.pos() for i in self.selectedItems()}

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.oldPositions:
            self.itemsMoved.emit(self.oldPositions, 
                {i:i.pos() for i in self.oldPositions.keys()})
        self.oldPositions = {}


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.gv = MyGraphicsView()
        self.scene = MyGraphicsScene()
        self.gv.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.gv)

        toolBar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, toolBar)
        self.undoStack = QUndoStack()
        toolBar.addAction(self.undoStack.createUndoAction(self.scene))
        toolBar.addAction(self.undoStack.createRedoAction(self.scene))

        self.populate()

        self.scene.itemsMoved.connect(self.itemsMoved)

    def itemsMoved(self, oldPositions, newPositions):
        self.undoStack.push(ItemMovedUndoCommand(oldPositions, newPositions))

    def populate(self):
        scene = self.gv.scene()

        for i in range(500):
            x = random.randint(0, 1000)
            y = random.randint(0, 1000)
            rect = CustomQGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y)
            scene.addItem(rect)
```

Comment: Thanks, i just realised how stupid I was :D